# Meteor.loginWithFacebook not storing email address

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using

- [accounts-password](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-password)
- [accounts-facebook](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-facebook)
- [service-configuration](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/service-configuration)

On the server:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: 'facebook'
});

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
    { service: 'facebook' },
    { $set: {
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
    }
);
```

On the client:

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({requestPermissions: ['email']}, function(error){
  if (error) {
    throwError('Could not log in');
  } else {
    // success
  }
});
```

This configuration prompts the user for Facebook verification with access to email and returns no errors. A new user is stores with the correct name and ID. But this e-mail is not stored in the user object.

This is what I get when i fetch a user from the shell.

```
{ _id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  createdAt: Mon Jul 13 2015 13:36:21 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  services: 
   { facebook: 
      { accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...',
        expiresAt: 1441971380621,
        id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        name: 'xxxx xxxxxx' },
     resume: { loginTokens: [Object] } },
  profile: { name: 'xxxx xxxxxx' } }
```

Why is the email address from Facebook not being stored?

Comment: Added issue with Meteor https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4743 and code for reproducing the bug: https://github.com/KnutSv/Meteor-facebook-login-email-bug

Answer (score 2):

While I have reported the issue to [Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4743) I've found a quick fix for the time being.

On the server run this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (user.hasOwnProperty('services') && user.services.hasOwnProperty('facebook')  ) {
    var fb = user.services.facebook;
    var result = Meteor.http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/' + fb.id + '?access_token=' + fb.accessToken + '&fields=name,email');

    if (!result.error) {
      _.extend(user, {
        "emails": [{"address": result.data.email, "verified": false}],
        "profile": {"name": result.data.name}
      });
    }
  }

  return user;
});
```

[EDIT]

The previous code works, but since it causes problems with other login methods I went with another approach:

In the client I call a function on the server when the user authenticates with Facebook:

```js
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({requestPermissions: ['email']}, function(error){
  if (error) {
    //error
  } else {
    Meteor.call('fbAddEmail');
  }
});
```

And then on the server:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.methods({
    fbAddEmail: function() {
      var user = Meteor.user();
      if (user.hasOwnProperty('services') && user.services.hasOwnProperty('facebook')  ) {
        var fb = user.services.facebook;
        var result = Meteor.http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/' + fb.id + '?access_token=' + fb.accessToken + '&fields=name,email');

        if (!result.error) {
          Meteor.users.update({_id: user._id}, {
            $addToSet: { "emails": {
              'address': result.data.email,
              'verified': false
            }}
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API may not return the email address for some users even if you asked for the "email" permission. The [official API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) state that:

> [email] field will not be returned if no valid email address is available.

One of the reason may be an unconfirmed email address and another one a user who registered with a mobile phone number only.

Comment: Yes, I've also come across that. But this is my personal Facebook account which I know for a fact has a valid and verified e-mail address. I even see the correct e-mail address when I choose to see more information about what I'm sharing in the pop-up window that is triggered from Meteor.

Comment: Really strange, I am getting the email addresses for several accounts in an app I am currently working on. The only difference is that I asked for two permissions `['public_profile', 'email']`, but I doubt it has anything to do with your problem

Comment: I've tried to add `public_profile` to the array, but it had no effect. Does it work for you when you run it on localhost? Could also be some kind of caching on Facebook's side, I first set it up without the email permission and then added it later on.

Comment: yes it worked during the development on localhost, and now it works on a production server, with the same Facebook accounts (old accounts with emails)

Comment: Looks like the reason is a change in Facebooks API from v. 2.4, now you have to request email in the graph call specifically: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/07/08/graph-api-v2.4/