# Meteor.loginWithFacebook Match Error: Expected string, got undefined in field email

Tags: facebook-graph-api, meteor, facebook-oauth, meteor-accounts

I've tried the solution presented in the question below, but still get this Match Error 400.
[Meteor.loginWithFacebook not storing email adress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382951/meteor-loginwithfacebook-not-storing-email-adress)

It is definitely logging in (I see the facebook account name, token etc)...I have tried it with and without {requestPermissions: ['email']}.

My client code is pretty standard:

```
    Template.login.events({
    'click #facebookLoginButton': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook(
            //{requestPermissions: ['email']}, 
            function(err){
                if(err){
                    Meteor.notifyHelpers.error('Apologies, there was an error with the facebook login process: ' + err.message);
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    Meteor.call('fbAddEmail');
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Any idea on potential causes/fixes? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the account you are trying to login with was not created with an email and rather a phone number?

Comment: nope - it is my personal facebook acct